# Software for recording motion from webcam (Windows) for free

Tags: windows-7, webcam

There's a few questions out there but none of them seem to have answers which fit my needs.

I need a webcam software which can record video when it detects motion, and a few seconds after the motion.  Ideally it would not save as JPEG files because those become huge and unwieldy.  I tried Yawcam, but that is difficult to configure, doesn't always go off, and saves a TON of jpeg files.

Is there a simple webcam software to detect motion that works on windows that is free?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a [short list of free options and reviews](http://www.video-surveillance-guide.com/webcam-motion-detection-software.htm).

Answer (score 3):

[Vitamin D Video](http://www.vitamindinc.com/) works for me.

Comment: This is one sweet piece of software, highly recommend it.